# MarkitUp Onclick event

Tags: onclick, markitup

I created a function that will transliterate text to different language. I have a button that works great:

```
<input onclick="translateAll()" type="button" class="button" value="Transliterate">
```

I'm trying to place that button on MarkitUp editor. I created a button:

```
{name: 'Translit', className: "translit", onclick:'translateAll()'},
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea how to call a function or if it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
{name: 'Translit', className: "translit", replaceWith: translateAll},
```